# Why the pattern matches one word while there is two identical word?

Tags: php, regex

Please take a look at this:

[image]

as you see there is just **one** matched in the *regex101*, but the browser matches **two** words which are identical. So why *regex101* cannot match the second word? Anyway I need to match both words *(or more if exists)*.

Noted that it isn't related to `g` flag. Because I've used it in the fiddle.

Here is the [fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/VWRELJ/1/)

Comment: These words - although look the same - are different. 1) `\uFEE3\uFEA0\uFEE0\uFEB2` and 
2) `\u0645\u062C\u0644\u0633`. See https://regex101.com/r/VWRELJ/3

Comment: Something about the RTL mode and probably Unicode? If you copy the same text to Notepad++ and try to search for the "مجلس", it also finds only one mach (the top one)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah .. isn't there any approach to match the words have identical look?

Comment: @naivists I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dealing with such a text is hard for later use. You have to find different representation of each letter to change search word from `مجلس` to something else like `احمدی نژاد` according to @Wiktor's solution.

That's why [normalization](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) process comes handy:

> Normalization is a process that involves transforming characters and
>   sequences of characters into a formally-defined underlying
>   representation. This process is most important when text needs to be
>   compared for sorting and searching, ***but it is also used when storing
>   text to ensure that the text is stored in a consistent representation.***

We need to normalize our input string at the very first place using [`Normalizer::normalize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) then without any change in Regular Expression, safely we can run a `preg_match_all` over it:

```
<?php

$text = <<< 'STR'
یک نماینده مجلس عنوان کرد: ﺩﺭ ﺩﻭﺭﻩ ﺍﺣﻤﺪﯼﻧﮋﺍﺩ ﻣﺮﺩﻡ ﺩﺭ
ﺭﻓﺎﻩ ﺑﻮﺩﻧﺪ !/دولت سابق تنها دولتی که پس از انقلاب به مردم خدمت کرد! ﻳﻚ
ﻧﻤﺎﯾﻨﺪﻩ ﮔﺮﻭﻩ ﭘﺎﻳﺪﺍﺭی دﺭ ﻣﺠﻠﺲ ﺷﻮﺭﺍﯼ ﺍﺳﻼﻣﯽ ﺩﺭ ﭘﺎﺳﺦ ﺑﻪ ﺳﺆﺍﻟﯽ ﺩﺭ ﻣﻮﺭﺩ
ﺑﺎﺯﮔﺸﺖ ﺍﺣﻤﺪﯼﻧﮋﺍﺩ ﺑﻪ ﻋﺮﺻﻪ ﺍﻧﺘﺨﺎﺑﺎﺕ ﺍﻇﻬﺎﺭ ﺩﺍﺷﺖ : ﻣﺎ ﺍﻣﯿﺪﻭﺍﺭﯾﻢ ﺍﯾﻦ ﺍﺗﻔﺎﻕ
ﺑﯿﻔﺘﺪ ﻭ ﺍﺣﻤﺪﯼﻧﮋﺍﺩ ﺑﺮﺍﯼ ﺷﺮﮐﺖ ﺩﺭ ﺍﻧﺘﺨﺎﺑﺎﺕ ﺣﺎﺿﺮ ﺷﻮﺩ چرا که دولت وی تنها
دولتی است که پس از انقلاب به مردم خدمت کرده است.
STR;


$normalizedText = normalizer_normalize( $text , Normalizer::NFKC );
preg_match_all('~مجلس~', $normalizedText, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => مجلس
            [1] => مجلس
        )

)
```

*Note: it needs `php_intl.dll` extension to be enabled.*

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/1fgDA)

Comment: Great ... which city?

Comment: Ok, I will remove all *unrelated-to-the-question* comments after this conversation. Do you have a job?

Answer (score 1):

The words are written with different chars that look the same but have different Unicode codes.

- The first word: `\uFEE3\uFEA0\uFEE0\uFEB2`
- The one not matched (with `... FORM` in the name): `\u0645\u062C\u0644\u0633`

Here are the codes:

```
‎FEE3  ARABIC LETTER MEEM INITIAL FORM
‎0645  ARABIC LETTER MEEM

‎FEA0  ARABIC LETTER JEEM MEDIAL FORM
‎062C  ARABIC LETTER JEEM

‎FEE0  ARABIC LETTER LAM MEDIAL FORM
‎0644  ARABIC LETTER LAM

‎FEB2  ARABIC LETTER SEEN FINAL FORM
‎0633  ARABIC LETTER SEEN
```

You cannot match both with a literal representation of either words, you either need to use an alternation with the two/all variants, or use character classes for those chars:

```
[\x{FEE3}\x{0645}][\x{FEA0}\x{062C}][\x{FEE0}\x{0644}][\x{FEB2}\x{0633}]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uUUPA6/1).

A [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Y4hfLn):

```
$re = '/[\x{FEE3}\x{0645}][\x{FEA0}\x{062C}][\x{FEE0}\x{0644}][\x{FEB2}\x{0633}]/u';
$str = 'یک نماینده مجلس عنوان کرد: ﺩﺭ ﺩﻭﺭﻩ ﺍﺣﻤﺪﯼﻧﮋﺍﺩ ﻣﺮﺩﻡ ﺩﺭ ﺭﻓﺎﻩ ﺑﻮﺩﻧﺪ !/دولت سابق تنها دولتی که پس از انقلاب به مردم خدمت کرد! ﻳﻚ ﻧﻤﺎﯾﻨﺪﻩ ﮔﺮﻭﻩ ﭘﺎﻳﺪﺍﺭی دﺭ ﻣﺠﻠﺲ ﺷﻮﺭﺍﯼ ﺍﺳﻼﻣﯽ ﺩﺭ ﭘﺎﺳﺦ ﺑﻪ ﺳﺆﺍﻟﯽ ﺩﺭ ﻣﻮﺭﺩ ﺑﺎﺯﮔﺸﺖ ﺍﺣﻤﺪﯼﻧﮋﺍﺩ ﺑﻪ ﻋﺮﺻﻪ ﺍﻧﺘﺨﺎﺑﺎﺕ ﺍﻇﻬﺎﺭ ﺩﺍﺷﺖ : ﻣﺎ ﺍﻣﯿﺪﻭﺍﺭﯾﻢ ﺍﯾﻦ ﺍﺗﻔﺎﻕ ﺑﯿﻔﺘﺪ ﻭ ﺍﺣﻤﺪﯼﻧﮋﺍﺩ ﺑﺮﺍﯼ ﺷﺮﮐﺖ ﺩﺭ ﺍﻧﺘﺨﺎﺑﺎﺕ ﺣﺎﺿﺮ ﺷﻮﺩ چرا که دولت وی تنها دولتی است که پس از انقلاب به مردم خدمت کرده است.';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => مجلس
    [1] => ﻣﺠﻠﺲ
)
```

Comment: @stack: I was curious if Java regex (that is much more internationalized, as  it handles Turkish dotless `i` matching well) could match these words with 1, and I could not. :)